# C# - Returning a bool response from another class using background worker

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I have a WinForm with a button that when clicked, calls a method in another class to upload a text file to Pastebin. The code origionally worked fine but locked the UI up until the upload had completed successfully so I'm now trying to complete this task using a background worker so the UI remains responsive.

The error I'm getting in Visual Studio is `Anonymous function converted to a void returning delegate cannot return a value`. I've looked at similar threads/google but can't quite understand what this means and how to go about correcting it.

My Upload button code:

```
private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.btnUpload.Enabled = false;
    this.btnUpload.Text = "Uploading...";
    if (Pastebin.UploadLog())
    {
        Clipboard.SetText(Properties.Settings.Default.logUrl);
        MessageBox.Show("Your logfile has been uploaded to Pastebin successfully.\r\n" +
            "The URL to the Paste has been copied to your clipboard.", "Upload successful!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The upload of your logfile to Pastebin failed.", "Upload failed!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    this.btnUpload.Text = "Upload";
    this.btnUpload.Enabled = true;
}
```

My code to complete the upload:

```
class Pastebin
    {
        public static bool UploadLog()
        {
            var upload = new BackgroundWorker();
            upload.DoWork += delegate
            { 
                Properties.Settings.Default.logUrl = "";
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

                System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection Data = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
                Data["api_paste_name"] = "RWC_Log_" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ".log";
                Data["api_paste_expire_Date"] = "N";
                Data["api_paste_code"] = File.ReadAllText(Properties.Settings.Default.AppDataPath + @"\Logs\RWC.log");
                Data["api_dev_key"] = "017c00e3a11ee8c70499c1f4b6b933f0";
                Data["api_option"] = "paste";


                WebClient wb = Proxy.setProxy();

                try
                {
                    byte[] bytes = wb.UploadValues("http://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php", Data);

                    string response;
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ms))
                        response = reader.ReadToEnd();

                    if (response.StartsWith("Bad API request"))
                    {
                        Logging.LogMessageToFile("Failed to upload log to Pastebin: " + response);
                        return false;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Logging.LogMessageToFile("Logfile successfully uploaded to Pastebin: " + response);
                        Properties.Settings.Default.logUrl = response;
                        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Logging.LogMessageToFile("Error uploading logfile to Pastebin: " + ex.Message);
                    return false;
                }
            };

            upload.RunWorkerAsync();

        }
    }
```

Comment: DoWork is an event handler, you can't return anything from an event handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use `async` functions instead of `BackgroundWorker`. You can make your `UploadLog` function `async` like the following.

```
public static async Task<bool> UploadLog()
    {


            Properties.Settings.Default.logUrl = "";
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

            System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection Data = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
            Data["api_paste_name"] = "RWC_Log_" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ".log";
            Data["api_paste_expire_Date"] = "N";
            Data["api_paste_code"] = File.ReadAllText(Properties.Settings.Default.AppDataPath + @"\Logs\RWC.log");
            Data["api_dev_key"] = "017c00e3a11ee8c70499c1f4b6b933f0";
            Data["api_option"] = "paste";


            WebClient wb = Proxy.setProxy();

            try
            {
                byte[] bytes = wb.UploadValues("http://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php", Data);

                string response;
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ms))
                    response = reader.ReadToEnd();

                if (response.StartsWith("Bad API request"))
                {
                    Logging.LogMessageToFile("Failed to upload log to Pastebin: " + response);
                    return false;

                }
                else
                {
                    Logging.LogMessageToFile("Logfile successfully uploaded to Pastebin: " + response);
                    Properties.Settings.Default.logUrl = response;
                    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logging.LogMessageToFile("Error uploading logfile to Pastebin: " + ex.Message);
                return false;
            }

    }
```

And then you can invoke your `async` function like that.

```
private async void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
this.btnUpload.Enabled = false;
this.btnUpload.Text = "Uploading...";
var result = await Pastebin.UploadLog();
if (result)
{
    Clipboard.SetText(Properties.Settings.Default.logUrl);
    MessageBox.Show("Your logfile has been uploaded to Pastebin successfully.\r\n" +
        "The URL to the Paste has been copied to your clipboard.", "Upload successful!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("The upload of your logfile to Pastebin failed.", "Upload failed!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
this.btnUpload.Text = "Upload";
this.btnUpload.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: if you want to use BackgroundWorker you must assign delegate that has two parameters like that.

      upload.DoWork += delegate(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e){}
and then set `e.Result=true` when it is necessary instead of returning value.

Comment: Thank's for the suggestion. That does seem to run now which is a plus, however I seem to be back to the original issue I first encountered of the UI being locked up wile the upload is completed.

Comment: Thank you too. As i mentioned in my comment you can achieve the same result by using BackroungWorker. Just add to `upload.DoWork ` event a delegate that has two parameters like that. `upload.DoWork += delegate(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e){}` and then use `e.Result=true` or `e.Result=false` when it is necessary instead of using return statement.

Comment: Thanks, missed that comment! I'll give it another try. :)

Comment: :) When you want to get result which you set in DoWork event you should use antoher BackgroundWorker event `RunWorkerCompleted` like that. `upload.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) { Messagebox.Show(e.Result.ToString())}`